# How to convert C# string to varchar PostgreSQL?

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql

I have problem with types mismatch - I think. I have application which connects with database and sends query. That is how it works:

```
string wartosc1 = "'letters'";

NpgsqlCommand command9 = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT * FROM RESOURCES WHERE TYPE = "+wartosc1, conn);
```

but when I try to execute it, there is answer:

```
System.FormatException: Input string was not in correct format.
```

I suppose that there is problem with type of variable because when I just input:

```
SELECT * FROM RESOURCES WHERE TYPE ='letters'
```

Everything is ok.

Any ideas?

Comment: what line throws the exception? the exception type suggests that it is not the constructor of the `NpgsqlCommand`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because when you write;

```
"SELECT * FROM RESOURCES WHERE TYPE = " + wartosc1
```

Your command will be like;

```
SELECT * FROM RESOURCES WHERE TYPE = letters
```

which is wrong because I suppose your `TYPE` column is some *text* type. If you solve this an easy way, you can add your `wartosc1` variable inside *single quotes* like;

```
"SELECT * FROM RESOURCES WHERE TYPE = '" + wartosc1 + "'"
```

### But please don't use this way.

You should always use [`parameterized queries`](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) in your commands. It prevents, forget to use some quotes, commas etc.. But more important this kind of string concatenations are open for [`SQL Injection`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

```
string wartosc1 = "letters";
NpgsqlCommand command9 = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT * FROM RESOURCES WHERE TYPE = @type", conn);
command9.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", wartosc1);
```

Comment: My variable was declared in this way:
string wartosc1 = " 'letters' "; 
-isn't it the same like in your first solution?
Anyway, now when I know about SQL Injection, I won't use it.

I have just tried your second solution but it didn't help, still have this Exception...

Comment: @Lorn Still you get `FormatException` on `NpgsqlCommand`? On which line exactly? Did you debug your code? Are you sure your connection string is right?

Comment: Ok, there was one more stupid mistake, now everything is wright. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use parameters to pass in the value to the query.

Read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8(v=vs.110).aspx on how to do that.

```
var wartosc1 = "letters";

var command9 = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT * FROM RESOURCES WHERE TYPE = @type", conn);
command9.Parameters.Add("@type", wartosc1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of string Interpolation using several variables and a date:

```
var dt = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30);
string wartosc1 = "letters";
string myStatement = $@"
    SELECT *
    FROM RESOURCES res
    WHERE res.DATE_EXAMPLE >= '{dt}' 
    AND res.TYPE = '{wartosc1}'
  "
```

**BEWARE** This sql string IS open to sql injection, simply by setting

```
wartosc1 = "somevalue' AND someOtherStatement 'thenDoSomethingBeforeApostrophe";
```

However, it may be that your environment doesn't need to worry about that... the apostrophes aren't necessary around an int, but forget it around a datetime, and you'll throw errors.